# User's rank on level on leaderboards

Tags: php, mysql

We have a time trial game and a MySQL database keeps track of each user's time. Here is a sample of what the table is organized like.

```
| level      | userid | time   |
--------------------------------
| levelone   | 1      | 7.00   |
| levelone   | 2      | 8.00   |
| levelone   | 3      | 9.00   |
| levelone   | 3      | 10.00  |
| leveltwo   | 2      | 22.00  |
| leveltwo   | 1      | 23.00  |
| levelthree | 3      | 14.00  |
| levelthree | 1      | 16.00  |
| levelthree | 2      | 18.00  |
```

So we have the name of the level the user completed, the user's ID, each which corresponds to a username, and the time which that user got on that level.

Note that this leaderboard allows each user to have more than one time. It keeps the old times and displays them on the leaderboard page. However, in this next case we want to ignore everything except the highest time per user.

We would like to be able to get a list of every level the user has played, and that works alright, but the tricky part is that we want to get that user's rank in relation to other users on the same level. So, from this table we want to return data like:

```
User ID 1 Has Played These Levels
| level      | rank | time  |
-----------------------------
| levelone   | 1    | 7.00  |
| leveltwo   | 2    | 23.00 |
| levelthree | 2    | 16.00 |
```

As you can see, user ID 1 beat everyone's times on level one. So, user ID 1 ranks first place on that level.

But user 1 was beat by user 2 at level two, so user 1 only ranks second place there.

We actually measure the time in milliseconds but I decided to write it in seconds here so my tables don't look confusing. I can easily get table two to show up, except I don't know how to get the rank without looping through every other user in the table, which is highly inefficient.

So here are some code bits I've seen floating around on SO that I've tried:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank FROM lb WHERE time < (SELECT time FROM lb WHERE userid = 1')
```

This makes sense, but when I try it, MySQL gives me an error:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Here's another:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, userid, time FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, userid, time FROM lb ORDER BY time DESC) AS t1
```

In addition to making no sense and having no way for me to only choose a specific level (it selects everything in the table) it takes about a minute to execute before eventually just timing out.

Does anyone know what I should do to obtain a player's rank on a level on a leaderboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for all levels using variables:

```
SELECT rank, userid, time
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@l = level, @rn + 1,
                        if(@l := level, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rank,
             userid, time
      FROM lb CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @l := '') vars
      ORDER BY level, time DESC
     ) t1
WHERE userid = @USERID;
```

This should have reasonable performance with an index on `lb(level, time, userid)`.  If performance is big issue and you have a large table, you may need to consider triggers.

Note:  this doesn't handle multiple times for a given user, because your example code does not handle this.

Comment: This works quite well! Can you please explain how it works though? I'm not as good at MySQL.

Comment: Briefly:  `order by` orders the rows by `level` and `time`.  The variable `@l` keeps track of the level.  When the value changes, then `@rn` is re-set to 1.  Otherwise, it is incremented.